# Merging hashes into arrays

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

I'm new in Ruby. I have two arrays of hashes

```
arr1 = [{"one"=> {"1"=> "a", "2" => "b"}, "two" => {"3" => "n", "5" => "h", "7" => "k"}]
arr2 = [{"one"=> {"8"=> "f", "11" => "r"}, "two" => {"7" => "o", "6" => "b", "14" => "b"}]
```

and I want to have one array like this:

```
arr3 = [{
"one"=> {"1"=> "a", "2" => "b", "8"=> "f", "11" => "r"}, 
"two" => {3" => 'n", "5" => "h", "7" => "k", 7" => 'o", "6" => "b", "14" => "b"}
]
```

so I want to merge hashes by keys and "add" their values. Can anyone help?

Comment: I believe you are missing some curly braces in initializationed arrays.

Comment: Still not right, you're missing a closing brace somewhere before the end of arr1 and again in arr2 and again in arr3. Mismatched quotes abound. All three arrays only have ONE element. What do you mean?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2947255/merging-arrays-of-hashes I would flag as duplicate but the answers to that question dates back to 2010 , could be useful though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
arr1 = [{"one"=>{"1"=>"a",  "2"=>"b"}, "two"=>{"3"=>"n", "5"=>"h",  "7"=>"k"}}]
arr2 = [{"one"=>{"8"=>"f", "11"=>"r"}, "two"=>{"7"=>"o", "6"=>"b", "14"=>"b"}}]

(arr1+arr2).each_with_object({}) { |g,h| h.update(g) { |_,o,n| o.merge(n) } }
  # => {"one"=>{"1"=>"a", "2"=>"b", "8"=>"f", "11"=>"r"},
  #     "two"=>{"3"=>"n", "5"=>"h", "7"=>"o", "6"=>"b", "14"=>"b"}}
```

This uses the form of [Hash#update](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html#method-i-update) (aka `merge!`) that uses a block (`{ |_k,o,n| o.merge(n) }`) to determine the value of the key `_k` when both hashes being merged have that key. (`_` in `_k` tells the reader that that block variable is not used in the block calculation.) `o` and `n` are the values of that key in `h` and `g` respectively.

For each key `k` equal to `"one"` or `"two"`, if the values (hashes) of `arr1.first[k]` and `arr2.first[k]` have a common key `l`, the merge operation will cause the value of `l` in `arr1` will be overwritten by the value of `l` in `arr2`. If, for example, `arr1.first["one"] #=> {"1"=>"a", "2"=>"b"}` and `arr2.first["one"] #=> {"8"=>"f", "2"=>"r"}`, the merge will return `{"1"=>"a", "2"=>"r", "8"=>"f"}`

Even though `arr1` and `arr2` each contain a single element (a hash), the code above works fine when the arrays contain multiple hashes, and when there are more than two arrays. If the arrays always contain a single hash, the arrays serve no purpose and we might instead just reference the hashes:

```
h1 = {"one"=>{"1"=>"a",  "2"=>"b"}, "two"=>{"3"=>"n", "5"=>"h",  "7"=>"k"}}
h2 = {"one"=>{"8"=>"f", "11"=>"r"}, "two"=>{"7"=>"o", "6"=>"b", "14"=>"b"}}
```

and replace `arr1+arr2` with `[h1+h2]`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the most elegant but this works:

```
arr1 = [{"one"=>{"1"=>"a",  "2"=>"b"}, "two"=>{"3"=>"n", "5"=>"h",  "7"=>"k"}}]
arr2 = [{"one"=>{"8"=>"f", "11"=>"r"}, "two"=>{"7"=>"o", "6"=>"b", "14"=>"b"}}]
arr3 = []
arr1[0].each_key{|k| arr3<< {k => arr1[0][k].merge(arr2[0][k])}}
arr3
```

If you don't know how many hashes your original array will contain, simply replace `arr1[0].each_key` with `arr1.each_index{|i| arr1[i].each_key` and replace `0` with `i` in the merge.